# how to only show some of the fields in an INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following as my results.. the problem is I only want 1 field from the balances table and 2 fields from the userinfo table... if I replace the *  with say user,avatar   I get my error...

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userinfo INNER JOIN balances ON userinfo.user        =       balances.user ORDER By balance DESC,avatar");
if (!$result) {
die("Query to show fields from table failed");
```

I do not know the proper form and cant find it anywhere

TIA
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as `user` column exists in both the joined tables `userinfo` and `balances` you need to prefix the table  name while accessing the column

Try

```
SELECT userinfo.user, userinfo.avatar, balances.balance
FROM userinfo 
INNER JOIN balances 
ON userinfo.user = balances.user 
ORDER By balance DESC,avatar
```